# How can I use GDB with strace to find a memory leak?

Tags: debugging, process-management, strace, gdb, memory-leaks

I have a C++ program which:

1. Allocates memory (always the same amount)
2. Should deallocate all that memory
3. Repeats

And I'm using the method I found [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/deathandthepenguinblog.wordpress.com/2015/08/15/poor-mans-memory-leak-detection-with-strace/amp/) to know if all the memory is deallocated properly. But it turns out that every 15 or so iteration my program requests more memory, which in theory shouldn't happen.

I want to know where and why is that memory requested, and what isn't being deallocated which causes the program to request more and more memory as time passes.

I can use GDB for this. What I thought to do was: run `strace` with my program for a little. Interrupt the program and hook GDB to it by passing it's process number to GDB. And then (maybe?) try finding out what's going on by using (maybe?) the `examine` GDB command (as strace prints the address at which memory is allocated, which I can use with GDB).

However, I am not sure this is the way to go, and I'm also not completely sure on how to stop my program whitout stopping its process. Any help?

Comment: have a look at valgrind and friends. The question as it is, is too broad, and more appropriated for stack overflow. If properly reworded, it could have a place here.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro I'm on Android using Termux, Valgrind isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider trying:

- http://valgrind.org/
- just stepping through suspicious parts of your code with gdb only = no strace (hint - https://cgdb.github.io/ interface might be handy)